How to modify a paragraph behavior setting programmatically?
I would like to alter/change a certain paragraph behavior plugin setting.
If I debug the paragraph entity, I can find the behavior_settings value, but it's json encoded and I don't think the best option is to decode it, change the values, encode it again and then assign it back to the paragraph, there must be a much better way.

You can get the behavior settings of a paragraph by calling getAllBehaviorSettings() on the paragraph entity:
$paragraph->getAllBehaviorSettings();

That will give you all the behavior settings of that paragraph.
But maybe you want to get a single value of the settings, you can do so with getBehaviorSetting($behavior_plugin_id, $key):
$my_paragraph_behavior_value = $paragraph->getBehaviorSetting($behavior_plugin_id, $key)

After you get the value and know the id of the behavior plugin you want to alter, use setBehaviorSettings($behavior_plugin_id, $key_value_array):
$paragraph->setBehaviorSettings($behavior_plugin_id, ['key' => 'new value']);
$paragraph->save;

